# Javascript library not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js in a rails project and it works perfectly fine on my local machine. On Heroku, it's as if it's not there. The javascript file is in app/assets. I looked at the compiled js that is served on heroku and parsley is definitely in there, but I'm not seeing it actually working.

I'm not even sure how to start troubleshooting this. What could be the issue?

Comment: Has it ever worked on production, or only locally?

Comment: Thanks for asking... I rolled back to a commit from 2 weeks ago and that it works there. I'm not sure what I would've changed in that timespan to break it though...

Comment: Are you precompiling assets, and if so have you cleaned since your last precompile?

Comment: I'm not precompiling.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue on heroku...

Comment: What I just did is set config.assets.version to the next version and use the minified version of parsley js. It's working now.

Comment: @AnthonyDeSimone, If you are using get, use get bisect to narrow the commit where it broke.  It uses bisection method to narrow it down fast and saved my bacon more than once

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before. But I make some changes in `enviroments/production.rb` file. First, try to add this line:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

This should be enough. But if you hold your asset files in special locations, you may also add the line like this: `config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)`, where you should specify your locations.